# how to play only one sound at a time with AVAudioplayer

Tags: iphone

i am playing sound when user tap on the respected button.

i have 10 buttons with 10 audio files.

i am playing the selected sound by using the AVAudioPlayer

```
AVAudioPlayer *myaudio=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:[sounds objectAtIndex:button.tag] ofType:@"mp3"]]error:NULL];
[myaudio play];
```

Now i have a problem that if i click another button before completion of playing previous sound then both sounds are mixed and getting noise.

I need to play second sound after completion of first sound.

i mean at a time only one sound will be played.

How can i done,can any one please help me.

Let me add comment if this question is not understandable.

Thank u in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i resolve my problem like this

```
if (soundplay == 0) {
        myaudio=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:[sounds objectAtIndex:x] ofType:@"mp3"]]error:NULL];
        myaudio.delegate = self;
        soundplay = 1;
        [myaudio play];
    }

- (void) audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying: (AVAudioPlayer *)myaudio successfully:(BOOL)flag {
    soundplay = 0;
    NSLog(@"sound fnished");
}
```

where soundplay is integer variable

Comment: But if i click button once it will start playing sound.. And if i again click it then it will start different instance of sound with gap.... I dont want to disable button.... So how could i handle the second click.. ???

Answer (score 0):

@Mahesh you can create a `AVAudioPlayer` class variable and in the IBAction function you can do something like this:

```
if([myaudio playing])
     [myaudio stop];
myaudio=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:[sounds objectAtIndex:button.tag] ofType:@"mp3"]]error:NULL];
[myaudio play];
```

Answer (score 0):

dont create different objects of AVAudioPlayer . create singletone object for AVAudioPlayer . and using this object just check with that object player is playing or not .

```
if([myaudio playing])
{
    [myaudio stop];
    myaudio=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle     mainBundle]pathForResource:[sounds objectAtIndex:button.tag] ofType:@"mp3"]]error:NULL];
    [myaudio play];
}
```

Comment: i am getting warning: 'AVAudioPlayer' may not respond to '-playing' and application quits

Comment: see sample code avTouch from iOS reference library for reference.